# Dr Racket fails when trying to create ]

Tags: racket

I'm playing around a bit with DrRacket in the BSL language.

When I'm trying to create a comment like so:

;; Hi(10, 50]

The program fails in the moment when typing the ]. I can only end it via TaskManager. It uses 13 CPU in the TM.

Has anyone of you a solution for that? or is it simply not to use ].

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is some bug that was [reported several times](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=13856) recently, and there's no fix, yet.  It's probably a result of some non-english keyboard layout (which was the case in these reports).  Hopefully it will get fixed soon...

UPDATE: The bug was fixed for the next release, but in the meanwhile Matthew posted some instructions on how to do a temporary fix -- repeated here for reference:

> We have tracked down a problem that occurs when the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is needed
>   to type <kbd>]</kbd>.
>
> DrRacket gets stuck due to a bad implementation of an operation that is
>   intended to be bound to <kbd>Alt-]</kbd>. For most of you, though, the problem is
>   that you didn't want the <kbd>Alt-]</kbd> keybinding at all; you're just trying to
>   type <kbd>]</kbd>, and it's misinterpreted as <kbd>Alt-]</kbd>.
>
> You can work around the problem by placing the five lines at the end of
>   this message in a file, and then selecting the file via the
>
> ```
> Edit -> Keybindings -> Add User-defined Keybindings...
> ```
>
> menu item in DrRacket. Typing <kbd>]</kbd> should work immediately after, and
>   typing <kbd>[</kbd> will also give you just <kbd>[</kbd> (instead of <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>).
>
> Beware that after you select the file, it will be difficult to unselect
>   it. It turns out the the menu item to un-select a keybindings file is
>   also buggy! Your best bet is to put the file in a place that it can
>   stay. (You can still edit the file and restart DrRacket if you just
>   want to drop the bindings.)

Comment: All right, thank you.
So I'd need these 5 lines which I can't find anywhere. I tried it with Google, but I couldn't ind a fix.